# Shipping SQL server database with my application

Tags: sql

I wish to ship SQL server database file with my application.  I am very very new to SQL.

1) I do not know how to protect this file from being opened.

2) If this file is emailed, can anybody read it?

3) Is there any possibility of protecting it like Access database is password protected so even emailed, no one can open it.

Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular SQL Server database files (.mdf, .ldf) aren't intended to be shipped with your application and installed locally - they are intended to be used on a SQL Server instance, running in a secure environment where typical users don't have physical access to the files per se.

As such, .mdf/.ldf files cannot really be protected by a password or anything like that - you can define users and their permissions, but that only applies to the permissions *inside* the database - not the database file(s) itself.

For your scenario, I guess you'd be better off with **SQL Server Compact Edition** - an in-process (just a bunch of DLL's), one-file-for-your-entire-database (*.sdf) kind of database - much more closely an Access replacement than the full-fledged SQL Server.

The documentation clearly states:

> SQL Server Compact Edition was
> designed from the beginning assuming
> the user had access to the physical
> file. Without an additional security
> mechanism, the user could bypass your
> application and use tools such as
> MSQuery to view and edit the raw data.
> **SQL Server Compact Edition supports
> the ability to password protect and
> encrypt the data file**, thereby
> limiting access to your application
> which embeds the password. The
> password protection of the database
> file adds a layer of protection that
> travels with the file, making it
> harder to access the data in the event
> a rogue user obtains the file.

Read more about [SQL Server Compact 3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019) and you might also want to check out the [SQL Server Compact blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlservercompact/) which discusses the latest developments (SQL Server Compact 4.0 is in testing right now).

Answer (score 1):

1) Assign a username and password to through SSMS or Enterprise Manager

2) No, because of [1]

3) Yes, because of [1]

Just to be doubly sure: take the database offline, zip encrypt .mdf file, and send it

Comment: Could you advise me the steps of assigning the user name and password you mentioned?

Comment: but if I'm an evil hacker and I get my hands on that MDF file, I can always restore it to a SQL Server instance of my own and make myself an admin in that database - so really, there's no real protection here.

Comment: You cannot restore the .mdf file if you cannot read it (as it would encrypted and password protected). I did just this a few years back. In UK, this is sufficient to comply with 1984 act.

Comment: @user415037: The username and password should be specified in your connection string - Just take the .mdf file and zip it up using zip's password protection and encryption. Then send the zip file. This is safer and less bother.

Answer (score 0):

If you ship it - than someone on the other end need to open and install it.

You can protect the file using zip software with password, and tell it to the other party on the phone.

Comment: But what if someone opens it from User's computer?

Answer (score 0):

1) Even if you protect it before it is added to the SQL server the user will be able to get into the database once it is loaded and running on the server.

2) Possible, but why would you want to email a database file?

3) When you email it you can add it to an archive with password, like a password protected zip file.

Comment: I am not emailing it, anybody who has access to that computer can do so.  No protection like Access password?

Comment: @user415037: no, you **cannot** protect the SQL Server file per se. But you **can** define users and permissions on that database to define who can do that. But anyone with a SQL Server instance could restore that file and "take control" of it - there's no "prevent this file from being used" kind of protection